# question about virtual environments from conda to virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda, miniconda

I have been working on a project in python that its inside an environment created at a linux machine. I recently got a new pc and i tried freebsd so i decided to see if i can port the settings, since these environments are supposed to be platform independent.

Since there is no support for conda in freebsd, i decided to write a script to migrate the dependencies from conda to virtualenv. The script, although it translates the .yml file into the .txt file needed for pip to install the dependencies, i can see that there are still a lot of packages missing, especially from the dependencies label in the .yml file.

Does it mean that these packages are not yet ported on freebsd or is there a different way to add them in the .txt file instead of just their name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that these packages are not yet ported on freebsd or is there a different way to add them in the .txt file instead of just their name?

It sounds like `pip` can't find a number of your dependencies, so yes.

Keep in mind that `conda` and `pip` are completely different build systems, despite being mostly compatible with each other and despite most packages available on one being available on the other. This also means that `conda list` usually includes some packages you don't necessarily need to install via `pip`. So you may be better off starting from scratch with a new `requirements.txt` file that includes the packages you actually need, and just let `pip` find what else it needs (which, again, is likely different than what `conda` needs).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried to do that and it even fails on installing coverage(technically pip installed it but when i tried to run it there was an issue with a module _sqlite3 : module not found). I tried to install that and i dont get how the installisation succeeded and the runtime failed. I was wondering if i can build the miniconda environment from scrath eg download some raw code and compile/build. Is that possible? If pip cannot find them in the virtualenv, could they be found in the conda environment?

Comment: In principle you could build everything from source; however I'd recommend building it from the actual source, not tarballs within a particular package manager. This all might be better solved using a FreeBSD package manager, if one provides these dependencies. (If this was Linux, it would be worth a shot using the distro's package manager directly). I'm not very familiar with FreeBSD, so I don't think I'm going to be much help, sorry. It looks like you're not the first person to run into this, maybe the FreeBSD community and their forums have some answers.